# Odd Task Parallel Library InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, dispose

I have the following code to build an advanced data structure which is pulled from SQL Server, then when the retrevial of that data is complete I update the UI. The code used is

```
private void BuildSelectedTreeViewSectionAsync(TreeNode selectedNode)
{
    // Initialise.
    SqlServer instance = null;
    SqlServer.Database database = null;

    // Build and expand the TreeNode.
    Task task = null;
    task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        string[] tmpStrArr = selectedNode.Text.Split(' ');

        string strDatabaseName = tmpStrArr[0];

        instance = SqlServer.Instance(this.conn);

        database = instance.GetDatabaseFromName(strDatabaseName);
    }).ContinueWith(cont => {
        instance.BuildTreeViewForSelectedDatabase(this.customTreeViewSql,
            selectedNode, database);

        selectedNode.Expand();

        task.Dispose();
    }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion,
        this.MainUiScheduler);
}
```

This works as it should on my main development machine; that is, it completes the build of the `database` object, then in the continuation update the UI and disposes the `task` (Task object).

However, I have been doing some testing on another machine and I get an `InvalidOperationException`, this is due to the `task.Dispose()` on `task` which still in the `Running` state, but the continuation `cont` should never fire unless the task has ran to completion.

Here's what the code looks like in the debugger when the exception is thrown:

[image]

[I am aware that it almost always unneccessary to call `Dispose` on tasks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/25/10287435.aspx). This question is more about why the continuation is firing at all here?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is simple, you are calling [`Dispose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) on the continuation itself and *not* on the first task

Your code consists of:

```
Task task = null;
var task = <task 1>.ContinueWith(t => { 
    /* task 2 */ 

    task.Dispose();
});
```

In the above code, `task` is equal to the continuation ([`ContinueWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696.aspx) doesn't pass back the original [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx), it passes the continuation) and that's what's getting captured in the closure you're passing to `ContinueWith`.

You can test this by comparing the references of the `Task` parameter passed into the `ContinueWith` method with `task`:

```
Task task = null;
var task = <task 1>.ContinueWith(t => { 
    /* task 2 */ 
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(t, task))
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Trying to dispose of myself!");

    task.Dispose();
});
```

In order to dispose of the first, you need to break it up into two `Task` variables and capture the first `Task`, like so:

```
var task1 = <task 1>;
var task2 = task1.ContinueWith(t => {
    // Dispose of task1 when done.
    using (task1)
    {
        // Do task 2.
    }
});
```

However, because the `previous Task` is passed to you as a parameter in the `ContinueWith` method, you don't need to capture `task` in the closure at all, you can simply call `Dispose` on the `Task` passed as a parameter to you:

```
var task = <task 1>.ContinueWith(t => {
    // t    = task 1
    // task = task 2
    // Dispose of task 1 when done.
    using (t)
    {
         // Do task 2.
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't belive this correct. You cannot define a task & a continuation in the way you do in your first snippet. To reference `task` in the continuation you must create an instance of the `Task`, then assign to it. `var task = TaskFactory.StartNew...(() => { ... }).ContinueWith(cont => { task.Dispose();});` will _never_ work as `task` is not 'in scope'. `var task = null;` then `task = TaskFactory.StartNew...(() => { ... }).ContinueWith(cont => { task.Dispose();});` will work, and the dispose acts on the `Task` object `task`, it does not refer to itself here - unless I have gone mental... :]

Comment: @Killercam Updated the code, the first snippet was just a replication of your code, and you're right, the variable had to be declared first so it could be accessed in the closure.  *That's not the important part though*.

Comment: @Killercam And it does refer to itself (whether or not you are mental is a distinction you have to make for yourself =P).  I've updated the answer to indicate how you can test it (see the new second code snippet).

Comment: are you sure about this. Why would the continuation take control of the initial task definition? Rather than linking task.continuation; take this; `var t = TaskFactory.StartNew(() => { ... });` then the continuation later `t.ContinueWith( MM => { t.Dispose; });` `MM` is the continuation delegate, not `t` right? This has flawed my understanding! :] Thanks again for you help...

Comment: @Killercam The continuation never takes control of the initial task definition.  It's simply how you assigned `task`.  You called `Task.StartNew` which returned the first task, but you didn't store *that* value, you called `ContinueWith` on the return value of `StartNew` and *that* was to the variable.

Comment: @Killercam Have you tried the second code snippet?  It's easy enough to see if you insert it in your code and run it.

Comment: Wow. Thanks this has helped my understanding alot. However, before you go and enjoy your 25 rep over a beer(s). If I did this: `var t = TaskFactory.StartNew(() => { ... });` and then I did this `t.ContinueWith( ant => { t.Dispose(); });` somewhere else, this is this disposing the continuation or the original `Task`? Also, why is this working on one machine and not the other?

Comment: @Killercam 25 rep?  From what?  Two upvotes = 20 rep =P.  If you do what you suggested in your comment, then that's the same as the third code snippet, you'd be disposing of task 1, *not* the continuation.  However, it then brings into light the last code snippet, in which the `Task` is passed to you and you don't have to worry about closures over the `task` variable at all (while achieving the same thing).

Comment: I will upvote and mark as the answer! I am gald you did not discount the beer option/reference! Right, so when you split the Task definition of t, and then assign a continuation on seperate lines this changes the way the intial task is referenced. Got it. I will check this over again tomorrow and run some tests to get this sorted. I thought I knew TPL well :'[. Have a good weekend...

Comment: @Killercam Ahh, well, I couldn't assume your upvote and accepting the answer. =)  Thank you.  Note, this isn't really an issue with the Task Parallel Library per-se, but with closures and scope.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you are trying to do above is equivelent to:

```
task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ...);
task.ContinueWith(cont => { ... task.Dispose(); });
```

However, what gets assigned to task variable with your code will be the ContinueWith work item, not the origninal StartNew work item.

More importantly, you probably don't even need to worry about task.Dispose() in this scenario.

The only time there is any real value in doing task.Dispose() is when there is a task.Wait() involved somewhere, which allocates an OS wait handle resource under the covers.

More info:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/parallelextensions/thread/7b3a42e5-4ebf-405a-8ee6-bcd2f0214f85

Comment: +1 for the reference to the fact that Dispose() is redundent here. I have posted a good article on this in my question. However, I don't believe what you have written about the task reference is right. Take your code above, if you do `Task t = TaskFactory.StartNew(() => { ... }).ContinueWith(c => t.Dispose());` this will NEVER work. However, `Task t = null;` then `t = TaskFactory.StartNew(() => { ... }).ContinueWith(c => t.Dispose());` will, and it will work on the original `t`, _not_ the continuation...